# python regular expression "12x4x67" match only the second group of numbers

Tags: python, regex

all i am a little stuck on this regular expression (Python beginner) I have a string here "12x4x67" and I need to split the numbers up into variables, for example: length, width and height. I have successfully gotten the first group. Now I need to match the second group. Here's a link to the regex tester I am using with the example I made.

Here is my [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1lU8/2):

```
\d+
```

It only matches `340` in `340x9x20`.

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1lU8/4). Find 1 difference :) However, I guess [`(?P<l>\d+)x(?P<w>\d+)x(?P<h>\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/mN3rS3/1) would be better, you will be able to access any of the parts via a named group.

Comment: You can use [`\d+\D+(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1lU8/7) and use captured group #1

Comment: awesome! i had the same thing before, but I only want the second match, do you know how I can perhaps do that? or maybe a foreach loop like for each match do this?

Comment: When asking a question please show your work.

Comment: @Muposat i did, the link is my work its just a string I know the rules.

Comment: I'm just using `(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)`, that way you're extracting the three variables. Now, do you have to use regular expressions for this? you could just use split function, couldn't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your input always has all 3 parts - length, width and height - you can use

```
(?P<length>\d+)x(?P<width>\d+)x(?P<height>\d+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mN3rS3/5)

With named captures, you will be able to access any of the parts via a named group.

[Python sample code](https://ideone.com/LQoTux):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(?P<length>\d+)x(?P<width>\d+)x(?P<height>\d+)')
s = "340x9x20"
m = p.search(s)
if (m):
    print(m.groupdict())
    # => {'length': '340', 'width': '9', 'height': '20'}
    print({k:int(v) for k,v in m.groupdict().items()})
    # => {'length': 340, 'width': 9, 'height': 20}
```

Comment: this is wonderful, how do I put the match of l into variable length now?

Comment: Could you clarify? `l` value can be obtained with `m.group("l")`. Then, you can do anything with it.

Comment: thankyou very much for your time and patience! it works, the concept of groups were a little confusing to me, but i completely understand them now!

Answer (score 4):

No regular expression needed:

```
length, width, height = "12x4x67".split('x')
```

Or if you prefer dealing with integers:

```
length, width, height = [int(s) for s in "12x4x67".split('x')]
```

Comment: wow this is a nice solution also, no regex required for this one, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer the split approach, but to answer your question about regexps - this will use `\d+` to find ALL occurences:

```
lwh = "340x9x20"
numbers = [int(n) for n in re.findall("\d+", lwh)]
print(numbers)       # [340,9,20]
```

this can be optimized by using a pre-compiled regexp.